# Swift 3 - sending the pointer of an optionally bound variable - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, swift3, xcode8

I am currently converting my swift files to swift 3 and there is a runtime exception that involves pointers. Here is the code:

```
var sectionChanges:NSArray? = nil
var rowChanges:NSArray? = nil

databaseView.getSectionChanges(&sectionChanges!, rowChanges: &rowChanges!, for: notifications, with: mappings)
```

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

> function signature specialization ) -> ()
>   to @callee_owned (@unowned Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer) ->
>   (@out ()), Argument Types : [@callee_owned (@unowned
>   Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer) -> ()]> of generic
>   specialization  of
>   Swift.StaticString.withUTF8Buffer 
>   ((Swift.UnsafeBufferPointer) -> A) -> A

EDIT:
Definition of getSectionChanges():

```
open func getSectionChanges(_ sectionChangesPtr: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray>?, rowChanges rowChangesPtr: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray>?, for notifications: [NSNotification], with mappings: YapDatabaseViewMappings)
```

Please help?!

Comment: Can you rewrite your `getSectionChanges` so it would just return tuple with changes arrays, instead of using `inout` parameters? Trust me, it will save you a lot of time and efforts in future.

Comment: Where does `getSectionChanges()` come from and how is it defined?

Comment: @user28434 that's a great suggestion, slipped my mind. But is there no way I can send a pointer of an optional variable?! GAH I hate these upgrades.

Comment: @MartinR, edited the question to include the function definition.

Comment: @KoushikKumar, for the edit with definition of `getSectionChanges`: change `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray>?` to `inout NSArray?`. And in future it's better to use swift's array with properly defined content type.

Comment: @user28434, I am using the YapDatabase Framework and the function is defined within the framework. I'm afraid I cannot edit the definition.

Comment: Well then, you may try using non-optional type with default empty array value, hm.

Comment: @user28434, that seemed to work! Thanks! I just hope it is stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialising the optional variable to something other than nil seems to have helped. Answering this question myself, in case it could be useful to somebody else.

```
var sectionChanges:NSArray? = NSArray()
var rowChanges:NSArray? = NSArray()

databaseView.getSectionChanges(&(sectionChanges)!, rowChanges: &(rowChanges)!, for: notifications, with: mappings)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the method definition implying: parameter AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer? won't accept address of nil NSArray object. So you should use the following code to call the method:

```
var sectionChanges = NSArray()
var rowChanges = NSArray()

databaseView.getSectionChanges(&sectionChanges, rowChanges: &rowChanges, for: notifications, with: mappings)
```

Comment: The thing is, sectionChanges and rowChanges have a possibility of being assigned a nil object.